# Can I have 2 different version of angular in one project

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to have 2 different versions of angular in the same project. Let say the wole project runs with angular v1.2, but I want to use a library which must run with a latest version.

Can I sandbox the library into a module that will run on a different version?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to?  Seems like a bad idea to me.  I understand that you have two versions.  Why would you not upgrade the older one now?

Comment: Too much work to upgrade

Comment: Sounds like you'll have to. Go get a shovel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the browser would recognize 1 of the installations. I believe angular does something like this:

```
(function(angular){
  // sets angular object in here
})(angular || {})
```

which essentially means that once one version of angular loads, the second one will see the first and not overwrite it.

You would have to rename one of the angulars to something else, and while I don't know the repercussions of doing so (if any), I wouldn't recommend.